# Markdown links in HTML embedded code

Tags: html, markdown, pelican

I want to introduce markdown links to other markdown documents. However, those links are within HTML tags. An example:

```
<dl class="section note">
    <dt>Note</dt>
    <dd>This is a Note, [link](path/to/file.md).</dd>
</dl>
```

Since the link is already inside HTML code, it is shown as is. Is there any way to do this?

NOTE: I am using Pelican static site generator.

Thank you!

Comment: To whoever downvoted, I would like to know why because the question is OK.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a way to do this in vanilla Markdown. If you're able to use the kramdown parser, you can do this by adding `markdown="span"` to the tags which need processing:

```
<dl class="section note">
    <dt>Note</dt>
    <dd markdown="span">This is a Note, [link](path/to/file.md).</dd>
</dl>
```

This produces the output:

```
<dl class="section note">
    <dt>Note</dt>
    <dd>This is a Note, <a href="path/to/file.md">link</a>.</dd>
</dl>
```

More details in the [kramdown syntax manual](http://kramdown.gettalong.org/syntax.html#html-spans).

Comment: But the `path/to/file.md` will be completely changed to `other/path/`file.html` when running Pelican, so it may happen that both sets are not compatible. I have to give it a try. Thank you!

Comment: It sounds like you're wanting either an include function or for a parser that will follow links and process them too - unfortunately I've never seen anything like that.